# how to bind data to listview in web

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am having Table `Tbl_purchase`.I want to show items in `Tbl_purchase` to `List view` control in my website .

First i tried to fill tha listview with `datasource` property through coding.I filled the datatable with data from `Tbl_purchase` and then my code is like

```
Listview1.Datasource=dt
ListView1.Databind()
```

But it shows an error like `itemtemplate is missing`.Then from show smart tag i selected datasource as `Tbl_purchase`,at that time it works for my web site.

But how can i fill listview throuh coding?Please help me.Thanks in Advance

Comment: show design code of listview...

Comment: i just simply drag listview control from tools<asp:ListView ID="ListView1" runat="server">
            </asp:ListView>

Answer (score 0):

When You add ListView directly from toolbox it doesn't have any templates...You will have to add the `templates` in order to show your data if you are doing it from codebehind...there are many templates present in ListView like `LayOutTemplate,ItemTemplate` etc.`ItemTemplate` is mainly used in most of datacontrols to show data...so you need to add these templates in your Design Code...Here is the very usefule article on the use of these templates in ListView...Please go through this...you will get the idea on how to go about it...[ListView Templates](http://www.codedigest.com/Articles/ASPNET/91_ListView_Control_in_ASPNet_35.aspx)